# Remove or replace exhaust fan assembly

Tags: bathroom, repair, bathroom-fixtures

I am trying to remove old exhaust fan in my bathroom. I took the grill and motor apart but I do not know how to remove the housing assembly. The reason I want to replace it because the higher cfm fan and motor (70 cfm) I bought is larger than the space where the fan fits. I am including the pictures of the fan housing. Let me know any suggestions on how to remove or find smaller fan blade with higher cfm.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there an accessible attic space above?

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely have to open the ceiling, remove the fan housing which was presumably nailed or screwed in place from the outside before the ceiling was fitted, install the new fan and repair the ceiling.

Drywall repair is a fact of life for getting things done, many times.

Answer (score 1):

**Hold on there.**

The fan was designed to have the motor replaced, that's why there is an AC socket there. And only one screw was used for the motor.

You may be able to buy a replacement motor, or more likely, the same model fan with a higher CFM motor.   Take the motor out of the new fan and put it in your old box.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the ceiling joist? Most likely the fan is fastened to the joist with nails. There's probably some "ears" on the housing where it's nailed to the joist. You should be able to pry the fan housing away from the joist. If you're careful you should be able to remove it without any major damage to the ceiling. Turn off the breaker and disconnect the wiring first. If you have a bigger fan then you simply cut the hole a little larger which is less work than putting in a smaller fan and patching the ceiling.